# Thread Ready and Completed Events

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I have some portion of code that needs to be executed in each thread (regardless of how it is spawned) running in a specific app domain just before the thread starts executing a code and after the execution completes.

I found that the **System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker** class has the event same as the second one that I need (see the table).

```
┌───────────┬────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ? class   │ BackgroundWorker class │ Description                                                             │
├───────────┼────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Ready     │ -                      │ Operation execution is about to start.                                  │
├───────────┼────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ ?         │ DoWork                 │ Execute operation.                                                      │
├───────────┼────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ ?         │ ProgressChanged        │ Notify about progress in execution of operation.                        │
├───────────┼────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Completed │ RunWorkerCompleted     │ Operation has completed, has been cancelled or has raised an exception. │
└───────────┴────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Are there events such as **Ready** and **Completed** from the previous table? I did not see such events neither on **System.Threading.Thread** nor **System.AppDomain** class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways to start new threads.  The thread pool is used not only by `QueueUserWorkItem` and `BackgroundWorker`, but also by any code that does asynchronous delegate invocations.  Also, the `Begin...` and `End...` methods for doing asynchronous things like `Stream.BeginRead` and `Stream.EndRead` start and end threads.  And, of course, there's the standard `Thread.Start()` when using managed threads.  And then there's the Task Parallel Library . . .

And, of course, there are the myriad ways of starting threads directly with the Windows API.

Even if you ignore the Windows API possibilities, you're still asking to hook a number of different mechanisms so that you can monitor activity.  You'd have to hook the managed thread functions as well as the thread pool functions that initiate and shut down work items.

A general solution to this problem probably isn't possible without some serious spelunking into the runtime library and doing all manner of nasty undocumented things in unmanaged code.  Even then, I'm not convinced it can be done.  The hooks you need just aren't exposed.

And if you want to include the Windows API possibilities ... well, good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are probably right. Thank you very much for the provided information.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want an event at/before the beginning of DoWork.

The event-model does not ptovide this because you can easily call a method

- just before RunWorkerAsync, from the calling thread
- immediately at the start of DoWork from the worker thread.

So there was no clear case for such an event.

Comment: I need to execute some portion of code before and after code execution by any thread. The solution you are suggesting is not complete because thread can be spawned after call to Thread.Start, for arbitrary delegate call and by ThreadPool to execute method queued for execution via QueueUserWorkItem method call.